# Listening to a UDP port

Tags: c++, udp

I need to connect to port 500 and print the data that comes through. Can someone point me in the right direction? Maybe a sample program..

Missed out a part.. using boost asio..

I used c/c++ with the following code :

```
  int z;
  struct sockaddr_in portList;
  int len_inet;
  int s;
  char dgram[512];
  time_t td;
  struct tm tm;
  s = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);
  if ( s == -1 ) {
    strerror(errno);
  }
  memset(&portList,0,sizeof portList);
  portList.sin_family = AF_INET;
  portList.sin_port = htons(500);
  portList.sin_addr.s_addr =  inet_addr("127.0.0.1");

  if ( portList.sin_addr.s_addr == INADDR_NONE ) {
    strerror(errno);
  }
  len_inet = sizeof portList;

  z = bind(s, (struct sockaddr *)&portList, len_inet);
  if ( z == -1 ) {
    strerror(errno);
  }

  for (;;) {
    z = recv(s, dgram, sizeof dgram, 0);
    if ( z < 0 ) {
      strerror(errno);
    }
    std::cout << dgram << std::endl;
  }
```

But all I get is garbage values like :

```
����҉
```

What was I doing wrong?

Comment: Google "c++ udp tutorial"?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) Also note that ports below 1024 are privileged, and may need you to run your program as administrator or root.

Comment: Welcome! Please take a couple of minutes to read the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). If you read it all, you'll get a badge (c:

Comment: do you want to a library such as boost or qt?
should it be system-independent? if not, which OS should it support?

Comment: did you check [Boost.Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html) documentation? here is [a synchronous UDP server example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tutdaytime5.html) and [asynchronous one](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tutdaytime6.html)

Comment: Consider reading Boost.Asio's [tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial.html) and [examples](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html).

Answer (score -6, accepted):

Look at beej's guide to socket programming

> http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/

Comment: [Link-only answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/148504) are considered poor form. Can you add some more details?

Comment: @Pradheep, This is a ridiculous answer. You are telling him to read an entire online networking book? section and the relevance to the question?

Comment: @enthusiasticgeek i gave the answer, when the question he asked was more open ended. if i remember right how should i write a udp server to listen on port 500  .so the simple answer was to refer the guide. he the code was added later. A suggestion "be curious not judgmental"